# created s3 presigned url (put) with custom headers with boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, python-3.6, boto3

My current code looks like this

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    'put_object',
    Params={'Bucket':bucket_name, 'Key':object_key},
    ExpiresIn=3600,
    HttpMethod='PUT' )
```

This is working, but I want to include custom headers like `x-amz-meta-my-custom-meta-data`. I'm pretty sure S3 supports this, so how can I do this with boto3?

Its not clear from the documentation.
Using Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a NO and is still classified as a feature request as of Oct 2017.

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1294

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I thought the answer might be no :(

Comment: Still a NO as of June 2018.... May have to downgrade to the old boto library for any services requiring this.

Comment: Actually.. it is possible. See my response

Answer (score 1):

Send it as metadata

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
'put_object',
Params={'Bucket':bucket_name, 'Key':object_key, "Metadata": {"mechaGodzilla": "anything is possible"}},
ExpiresIn=3600,
HttpMethod='PUT' )
```

In your request headers, you must include `x-amz-meta-mechaGodzilla: "anything is possible"`

Comment: If you use "get_object" there will be no "Metadata" parameter but you can use some other parameters for some headers like: ResponseCacheControl, ResponseContentDisposition, ResponseContentEncoding, ResponseContentLanguage, ResponseContentType, ResponseExpires.